# Blank page when integrating firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase. I am trying to add firebase authentication to my web application. When I import firebase (and add the authentication command into the code file to be executed on click of the sign in button), the webpage turns blank. Nothing shows up on the webpage, but the code compiles just fine. I have tried a couple different import commands for the firebase.js file, but none have fixed the problem. Below is the firebase.js file and the corresponding login.js login page file.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "***",
    authDomain: "***",
    projectId: "***",
    storageBucket: "***",
    messagingSenderId: "***",
    appId: "***",
    measurementId: "***"
  };

  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()

  export {auth, provider};
  export default db;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import './Login.css';
import { Button } from '@mui/material'
import { auth, provider } from './firebase'

function Login() {
 const signIn = () => {
     auth.signInWithPopup(provider).catch((error) => alert(error.message));

 }

  return (
    <div className = "login"> 
    <h1> Welcome to Chatlytic</h1>

    <div className="login__logo">

    </div>
    <Button onclick = {signIn}> Sign In</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro whu u use now obsolete /combat/app? Just use firebase/app import instead and it will work fine.

Comment: I actually tried that beforehand and it caused this error: 
export 'default' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/app'

The webpage loads with these import commands, but the google sign in doesn't pop up upon clicking the sign in button:

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

Comment: I think it is a version issue on your Firebase. Check your Firebase version using the npm command. i guess if it doesn't work on the latest version downgrade it. Update me on how it went.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).